# What criticisms of Wittgenstein's philosophy of language have been offered?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, semantics, contemporary-philosophy

In a [2003 obituary](https://philosophynow.org/issues/43/Donald_Davidson_1917-2003), [Anna Sherrat](https://philpapers.org/s/Anna%20Sherratt) described one of my many philosophy heroes, Donald Davidson, as “one of the greatest American philosophers.” She did an excellent job of summarizing one of the perspectives of one of the most respected philosophers of the 20th century, as follows:

> [W]e can ascribe beliefs to a speaker only on the basis of prior assumptions about meaning, and vice versa…there will be many different assignments of meaning and belief that fit equally well with a given speaker’s behaviour.

I understand that [Wittgenstein](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/) transformed the field of philosophy of language with his insight that while objective definitions consists of language, we understand linguistic utterances by interpreting subjective *meanings*, and we do that according to our individual histories of learning how those utterances were used by the people we’ve known to use them. In fewer words, *meaning* derives from *usage*.

As he wrote in *Philosophical Investigations, 1953*, “the meaning of a word is its use in the language” (Quoted [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#MeanUse) by Anat Biletzki). He invented the term “language games” to refer to the many different ways that language may be used.

In his [IEP article on philosophy of language](https://www.iep.utm.edu/lang-phi/), Michael P. Wolf reflects a consensus in the field that Wittgenstein’s theory, developed over half a century ago, has yet to be superseded:

> [I]t can be safely said that Wittgenstein rejected a picture of language as a detached, logical sort of picturing of the facts and inserted a concern for its pragmatic dimensions. One cannot look at the representational dimension of language alone and expect to understand what meaning is. https://www.iep.utm.edu/lang-phi/#SH3b

My question is: Does anyone here know of any philosophy book or article (published in that last fifty years), which offers cogent criticism to refute or weaken these theses?

Comment: How does the IEP quote on Wittgenstein "reflect a consensus in the field that Wittgenstein’s theory, developed over half a century ago, has yet to be superseded"? I don't see it.

Comment: @Eliran I'm guessing that this is because W's theory goes beyond the minimalism of D's theory by adding modal imagination to our concept of *meaning*.

Comment: "Refute" is a strong word.  Are you asking about criticisms.

Comment: @NickR I don't see how that says anything about "consensus in the field".

Comment: @Eliran, that’s exactly what my question is about. It’s designed to determine whether any other philosophers have published more cogent theories since those came out. What’s your experience…do you know of any? Are you familiar with recent books on philosophy of language which cover this topic? I wouldn’t have asked this question if I hadn’t read any; I’d do my own research first (and I did…did I ever!). I appreciate your question, because consensuses of expert opinions are the best objective knowledge which is available to us!

Comment: Also, @Eliran, the people who write those articles are selected because they’re extremely well versed in their fields. The point of these encyclopedia entries is to summarise the consensuses in the area, and also to note the controversies which are extant in the literature at the time of writing. If they quote a claim without describing a controversy about it, then you can rest assured that they’re aware of the state of the research...

Comment: @Rortian I don't dispute what the IEP entry says. The author's entry describes Wittgenstein's views (in the relevant section). But it's one thing to say that there is a consensus that those are Wittgenstein's views, and another to say that there is a consensus that Wittgenstein's views are correct. Do you mean the former or the latter? I think the author means the former, and I read your post as meaning the latter (but I may have misunderstood you).

Comment: @Eliran, I'll rephrase slightly for the sake of clarity. I see that my words weren't specific enough: "The point of these encyclopedia entries is to summarise the consensuses in the area, and also to note the controversies which are extant in the literature at the time of writing. If they quote a claim without describing a controversy about it, then you can rest assured that they’re aware of the consensus in the research."

Comment: It would help if you didn't have off-topic asides like the sentence about Sherrat complimenting Davidson. And this first paragraph is over-laboured too.

Comment: @curiousdannii! I understand what you're saying! I can't imagine what it means to you. This is not the first time that you've challenged me with your individual opinion which seems to have been uttered without regard to your own biases. I might ask you to explain yourself but I'd rather ask you whether your attitude might reasonably appear to thoughtful people as antagonistic?...

Comment: @curiousdannii  I don't want to opine about your intentions, but neither do I want to be the target of opinions which are uttered without a balanced approach, so I ask you instead: Are you certain that your beliefs are absolutely true? And if not, for what purpose did you create these utterances?

Comment: @Rortian Of course I'm not certain all my beliefs are absolutely true. Not sure what that's got to do with improving this question and helping you make it more focused and concise.

Comment: @curiousdannii,roflmao, why won't you answer other very reasonable questions? Perhaps you intend to help; perhaps you don't. I'm not clear on that yet, So far your your behaviour doesn't fit my picture of a reasonable critic.  People aren't always as they seem to be. IMO, It's absurd to think that we might be.

Comment: @Rortian No one owes you answers, especially when your questions often slight their thinking. If you stop writing as if most people can't account for their biases you might have some better interactions here.

Comment: This question has made the hot network questions list, so congrats for that!

Comment: @curiousdannii, ok then, I understand what you're saying, and if you weren't stating it as a  judgment of my personal style I'd be less offended. The same advice might be offered in a general form which doesn't characterise anybody, I trust you can get that. I'm willing to learn; I have no intention of ignoring good advice or repeating my mistakes. I'm simply overextended when it comes to people proffering superior knowledge, as if they're (usually; perhaps not always, but we can tell from their innuendo) compelled to demonstrate something about their identities.

Comment: @curiousdannii, after consideration, I request that you stop "helping" me. I don't consider that your intervention has been very effective, but I suspect that it might reasonably be interpreted as condescending. I don't grant you or anyone here the academic or moral authority to judge either my personality or the literary characteristics of my sincere attempts to produce educational events.  We all have our issues and our faults, and I haven't seen any evidence that my manifestations are objectively worse than anyone else's. Please pick on somebody else, or better still cut it out altogether.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92716/discussion-between-curiousdannii-and-rortian).

Answer (score 5):

Colin McGinn, in his book *The Philosophy of Language*, discusses at least four criticisms of Davidson's theory.

1. > Is it enough to say that knowledge of meaning is knowledge of truth conditions - especially when we restrict ourselves homophonic statements of truth conditions? Can't we ask what this knowledge of truth conditions itself involves?
2. > We need to assign more than reference to a name if we are to capture its full meaning. We need something like sense.  But Tarski's semantic apparatus does not specify sense. How then can it function as a theory of meaning. At best it is a theory of reference.
3. > Davidson's theory provides no explanation of how words come to have semantic properties.  The axioms say things like "'Hesperus' denotes Hesperus", but nothing in the theory tells us how it is that a word like "Hesperus" *acquires* reference. Similarly for predicates and satisfaction. The axioms do not explain what gives marks and sounds the semantic features they have.
4. > Davidson distinguishes sharply between giving logical forms for sentences and giving analysis of individual words. But how robust is that distinction? The intuitive idea that Davidson is working with is that in attributing logical forms we do not break words down into parts, but in lexical analyses we do. [Yet] Davidson's own theory of adverbs construes sentences containing adverbs as quantifications over events with predicates of events. The logical form here is quite different from the superficial syntax of the sentence.  The paraphrase finds hidden semantic complexity in adverbs.  Why isn't this a case of lexical analysis?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd be happy to think a bit about it, but I'd need to have the words that Davidson and Colin used in order to deal with the meanings of the criticisms (and I have other priorities...!), but if you want to work with me we can figure this out. I have some questions about your questions, though.

*Is it enough to say that knowledge of meaning is knowledge of truth* 

Does this use of the term ‘knowledge’ refer to uncertain knowledge?

*Can't we ask what this knowledge of truth conditions itself involves?*

Umm, why wouldn’t we? Preconceptions don’t work in my perspective.

Comment: *2.We need to assign more than reference to a name if we are to capture its full meaning. We need something like sense. But Tarski's semantic apparatus does not specify sense. How then can it function as a theory of meaning. At best it is a theory of reference.*

Does "full meaning" refer to objective meaning? In the absence of "full" objectivity, I'm not clear that Davidson would dispute this...are you clear about what Davidson would think? Unfortunately, he won't be able to tell us...we can be *fairly* certain and quite *correct* about that...

Comment: 3. Umm, didn't Davidson accept Wittgenstein's approach?  Does McGinn agree?

Comment: *4.Davidson distinguishes sharply between giving logical forms for sentences and giving analysis of individual words. But how robust is that distinction?* Didn't Wittgenstein develop the theory of language games to overcome the insuperable difficulty of demonstrating that words carry meanings? Utterances occur in sociolinguistic contexts, right? They're interpreted - it seemed to some people and still does - according the history of learning of whoever connotes them...how do you assess how "superficial" syntax is or how "complex" the semantics are...why does that matter?

Comment: Is McGinn attempting to refute pragmatism?? Are you aware of his agenda? If you're willing to think about my questions and respond to them with your own ideas then you could drop me a line at [Higher Order Thinking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92382/higher-order-thinking).

Comment: @Rortian McGinn's book is an introductory, undergraduate level text which surveys ten classic papers in the philosophy of language.  I don't think he has an agenda, as such.  He characterises Davidson's response to such criticisms as being that from the point of view of philosophical semantics he has achieved his aim - namely, to specify meanings systematically and show how an "infinite mastery can proceed from a finite basis."  According to McGinn, Davidson leaves it to psychologists to say more about linguistic meaning.  I currently lack sufficient understanding to add to McGinn's comments.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I suggest (as hunbly as possible)  that my other two degrees in cognitive and neuropsych might have provided me with a rather broad set of insights into comprehension, motivation, learning and communication. I work interdisciplinarily, at the intersection of psych, phil and ed. Please drop by and exchange messages at your convenience...I've got work to do, but I'll respond to any questions that you've got on that stuff. I 'm at [Higher Order Thinking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92382/higher-order-thinking)

Comment: Although Davidson's and Wittgenstein's language philosophies are both in the pragmatic vein, they disagree both on the nature of language (truth conditional vs language games) and its acquisition, see e.g. [Verheggen, How social must language be?](https://philpapers.org/rec/VERHSM) For a comprehensive recent critique of the private language argument see [Azzouni, The Rule-Following Paradox and its Implications for Metaphysics](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319490601).

Comment: Thanks, @Conifold. I appreciate this information.

Comment: Great stuff, @Conifold. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One such book is Alain Badiou's "Wittgenstein's Anti-Philosophy".

Badiou agrees with Russell that "Tractatus" is a masterpiece, and his later philosophy (especially the "Philosophical Investigations") is a type of sophistry.

Another text that criticizes some features of Wittgenstein's later philosophy is Saul Kripke's "Naming and Necessity". This book has caused a quite big controversy in Wittgenstein scholarship.